# Python gmail api send email with attachment pdf all blank

Tags: python, pdf, gmail, attachment

I am using python 3.5 and below code is mostly from the google api page...
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending
slightly revised for python 3.x

i could successfully send out the email with the content text and an attachment pdf but the pdf attached is completely blank..

please help and thanks in advance

```
def create_message_with_attachment(bcc, subject, message_text,  file,sender='me' ):
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['bcc'] = bcc
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject

  msg = MIMEText(message_text)
  message.attach(msg)

  content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file)

  main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
  fp = open(file, 'rb')
  msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
  msg.set_payload(fp.read())
  fp.close()
  filename = os.path.basename(file)
  msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
  message.attach(msg)

  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  raw = raw.decode()
  return {'raw':raw}
```

Comment: What did you expect it to show?

Answer (score 11):

you just forgot to encode the attachment. Replace two lines of your code with those:

```
  import email.encoders

  ...
  msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',filename=filename)
  email.encoders.encode_base64(msg)
  message.attach(msg)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Small tip:  `import email.encoder` makes some conflict. like: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'encoders'`. Even there is no variable like `email` around. So, I solved the point like `import email.encoders as encoder` than 2nd line :  `encoder.encode_base64(msg)` solved.

Answer (score 0):

Less line of code, Seem to work well, but very slow :

```
def SendPDF(to, file, Server):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = ME
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = 'Send a pdf File'

    with open(file, 'rb') as PDFFile:
        PdfContent = PDFFile.read()

        msg.add_attachment(PdfContent, maintype='', subtype='pdf',
                           filename="The Pdf File Bro.pdf")
    Server.send_message(msg)
```

But I don't know what append with maintype, this argument is needed, and you can write whatever you want it will works, I didn't find actually any documentation on it.Don't manage SMTP enough to know it otherwise. If anyone know...